# Personal results while using Facebook Graph API search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app in which the user needs to search and select a person from Facebook. I'm able to search in the Facebook Graph API using "https://graph.facebook.com/search", however this only give very general results and not the 'close' people Facebook would normally suggest when searching in the search field on Facebook.com. In this case it is impossible to find someone with a regular name.
Does anybody know how I can personalize my query or go around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API search is not the same nor directly comparable to the search in the Facebook website.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search